# Terminal output turns black

Tags: python, linux, terminal

Short version: I have a program that prints to the terminal successive integer numbers in an infinite loop. At some point, the terminal became black, and no output is visible, but I can still execute commands.

*Details*:

I read [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/loop-without-looping/33218?noredirect=1#comment73885_33218) in PCG and wanted to try it in Python. Here it is:

```py
#!/bin/python2
class Dier(object):
   def __init__(self):
       global ct
       ct += 1
       print ct
   def __del__(self):
       Dier()

ct = 0
Dier()
```

This program loops indefinitely, printing the number of iterations on each step. Left overnight (we get to the tenths of millions in a matter of minutes) executed from an Ubuntu gnome terminal, the terminall just shows black. The program is still running, and new lines appear, but nothing is visible. I killed the program, but the terminal, including the command prompt, is black. I can input commands, and they work, but no output is visible.

Why is this happening?

Some information I provided in the comments:

- The memory used by the program (reported by top) remains constant and low.
- I can print absurdly large numbers to the terminal without getting this behaviour. The largest number I have printed has 10^10^6 digits (of course, the terminal has forgotten the beginning of it, and only shows the last digits, but its log10 is 1246124). My program couldn't have gone that far, that would take millions of times the age of the universe.
- On an added note, if I try to print something *ever bigger* than that, it just seems to freeze, using the CPU but without any output (while the original output was there, but invisible).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your assertion that "new lines appear, but nothing is visible"... If the new lines appear, then they're visible. Conversely, if nothing is visible, then how can you tell that new lines appear?

Comment: @twalberg the screen is black, but I can see the position of the cursor where I am writing.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "terminal"? xterm? gnome-terminal? Or do you mean your text console? Or do you mean an IBM-3101 plugged into the serial port of your PC?

Comment: @Robᵩ a gnome terminal, as said in the question.

Comment: So you did. I missed that.

Comment: I assume this has to do with the terminal buffer and the python output buffer. Have you tried calling sys.stdout.flush() each time? Interesting code...

Comment: PS: might be more elegant if ct were a class variable rather than global/module one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a gnome-terminal thing, not a python thing. I've experienced this after printing a ton of logs from a python script in gnome-terminal. Often the text reappears when I scroll, which would mean that obviously the error is post-sys.stdout.

Comment: @metaperture that does indeed seem to fit the evidence. I was wondering if there was a specific sequence that may trigger this. I am still surprised too much printing can make it crazy, as the scrollback is limited to 512 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the output is being buffered. You should try and change the print to

```
print ct, "\n"
```

or

```
print ct
sys.stdout.flush()
```

alternatively you can tell python to not buffer the output by calling it with `-u` parameter (see https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) or setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` env variable (see https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)

Comment: I don't have GNOME here to test it right now, but, why would the rest of the output be black? I killed the program, and I could still write commands, and they would all be black.

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()` does not change the behaviour.